# Equivalent of "UserProperties" property in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus SDK

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net

I am trying to migrate from the Legacy Azure service bus SDK to the new one "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus". I don't see the equivalent of the "UserProperties" property with the new Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusMessage. Where can I set the user properties? I see a property called "ApplicationProperties". Is that the one to go for?

```
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message msg = new Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.Body));

            if (message.Headers != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in message.Headers)
                {
                    msg.UserProperties.Add(item.Key, item.Value); //I need help for this statement. 
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `ApplicationProperties` is the new custom headers collection to use.